# How do i convert the following for loop with apply function?

Tags: for-loop, apply

The following for loop looks for duplicated label and concatenate a prefix to it (to make the label unique).The prefix is the label one row before (a section label).

```
for(i in 1:nrow(MStar_KR))
 {
   if (MStar_KR[i,1]=="Year over Year") 
   {
     MStar_KR[i,1]<- MStar_KR[i-1,1] %s+% "_" %s+% MStar_KR[i,1]
   }
}
```

I am a beginner in R. Is it possible to use the apply function for the same? Thanks

Comment: and the data frame has the following structure (dput(head(MStar_KR,5))):
structure(list(2011 = c("106,916", "46.9", "20,286", "19.0", "15,855"), 2012 = c("104,507", "48.1", "20,443", "19.6", "16,604"), 2013 = c("99,751", "48.6", "18,777", "18.8", "16,483"), 2014 = c("92,793", "50.0", "17,790", "19.2", "12,022"), 2015 = c("83,795", "50.3", "15,628", "18.7", "14,210")), .Names = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"), row.names = c("Revenue USD Mil", "Gross Margin %", "Operating Income USD Mil", "Operating Margin %", "Net Income USD Mil"), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
MStar <- function(x){
if (MStar_KR[i,1]=="Year over Year") {
       MStar_KR[i,1]<- MStar_KR[i-1,1] %s+% "_" %s+% MStar_KR[i,1]}
}

MStar_KR <- sapply(MStar_KR, MStar(x))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. i was a looping dummy variable, should it be left in the function(x) statement?  anyway, i tried, and got the following error with the sapply line:

Error in if (MStar_KR[i, 1] == "Year over Year") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @anycorp Are you trying to verify this over the entire `data.frame`?

Comment: yes, the "i" dummy variable will loop thru all the rolls in the data frame

Comment: It would be good to add `dput(head(df, 10))` so we get some data to work with.

Comment: structure(list(`2011` = c("106,916", "46.9", "20,286", "19.0", "15,855"),     `2012` = c("104,507", "48.1", "20,443", "19.6", "16,604"), 
    `2013` = c("99,751", "48.6", "18,777", "18.8", "16,483"), 
    `2014` = c("92,793", "50.0", "17,790", "19.2", "12,022"), 
    `2015` = c("83,795", "50.3", "15,628", "18.7", "14,210")), .Names = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"), row.names = c("Revenue USD Mil", "Gross Margin %", "Operating Income USD Mil", "Operating Margin %", "Net Income USD Mil"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Add that to your question please

Comment: and just wondering, in the function(x), what's the use of the dummy var i (which was used in the for loop)?

Comment: I used make.unique and worked around the above issue.  many thanks!

Comment: @anycorp Sorry I didn't get back to you, but glad that it's working.